# How to monitor and manage (start, stop, install, uninstall, update) OSGi bundles through a program

Tags: reflection, osgi

I am working on a project that requires to monitor and manage (start, stop, install, uninstall, update) OSGi bundles in an OSGi based application using pre-programed instructions, similar to java reflections, the OSGi application can reflect upon itself by monitoring itself and its context, it can update or remove some bundle or can add(install and start) a new bundle.

For example, there is a chat application developed using OSGi bundles. In order to add self-managing characteristics to it, there need to be a mechanism to monitor and manage (install/uninstall, start/stop, update) OSGi bundles autonomically (without human intervention or as little human involvement as possible). Any idea how this can be achieved?

I tried to explain the problem, but feel free to ask if you dont understand my question.

P.S. I am using OSGi Equinox framework.

Regards.

Comment: It probably depends on which OSGi framework you are using. Which one are you using?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, it's Equinox.

Comment: Why on earth does it make a difference what framework is used???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OSGi framework already includes such a mechanism and gives you full control over the bundles lifecycle using the most basic OSGi interfaces.

If you want to control it from inside an OSGi bundle, let's call it a management agent bundle, you can use the BundleContext of this bundle to:

[org.osgi.framework.BundleContext](http://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mBS_SDK/um/runtime/osgi/docs/framework/api/framework/index.html)

installBundle(java.lang.String location)
          Installs a bundle from the specified location identifier.
getBundles()
          Returns a list of all installed bundles.
getBundle(long id)
          Returns the bundle with the specified identifier.

Once you have the Bundle object, you can lookup everything about the bundle, like name, imported packages, etc; and start, stop, update the bundle. So, there you can implement whatever logic your zero-administration policy states (e.g. restart all plugin bundles when an error occurs, or search for a suitable plugin and install it when new content has to be rendered, or whatever)

Now, if you want to do all this from "outside" OSGi, you will have to publish some kind of interface for outside in your management agent bundle. One possibility could be a web page (OSGi contains a simple embedded web server, check the HTTPService). There are many others, depending on what you want to achieve.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed explanation :). Yes, it certainly helps to see the possible ways to get my problem solved. Thanks again.

Comment: @ندیم عباس  if this contribution answers your question, you should accept it to indicate that (1) you have a satisfactory response (2) this question does not need further attention, and (3) reward the user that shared his/her knowledge to help you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `org.osgi.framework` [javadoc](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/package-summary.html). From the [bundle context](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) of your bundle, you can install and get bundles. The [bundle](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html) API allows you to stop, start, and update bundles.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it definitely shows the way to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

The [BundleListener](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleListener.html) class might also be useful to you, it will notify you of any bundles starting or stopping.

Comment: Thanks dear for the suggestion, it helps me to move forward :)

Comment: Don't use the BundleListener, there is a BundleTracker that is MUCH easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Apache Felix FileInstall source code. It is probably the simplest 'management agent' that can be used to fully manage an OSGi framework (including the oh so important Configuration Admin).